# com.whatsapp_preferences.xml periodically gets overwritten how to prevent that from happening

Tags: security, permissions, app2sd, customization, systemless-root

on a `magisk rooted Android` 10 device
`com.whatsapp_preferences.xml`

( `/data/data/com.whatsapp` ? ... can't remember that `path` now )
has been updated with non default parameters as I needed but it periodically gets overwritten *how to prevent that from happening.*

**what I did so far**

even if `reMount` the `partition` as read write ( for my convenience I do it using `total commander` with `root`  though  I haven't tried I would assume it would end up the same way if I did it on `command` line ) it will not let me overwrite the original file with my modifications   & but if I  delete the original and `copy` the modified file that is allowed.  funny...why   ?
I did this and then `chown` (  to  `root` ) & `chmod` ed it to 444 then force stopped the app
cleared `cache` .new settings were working until next day I landed up with the same old file that it overwrote

**question**

now I am aware that for `WhatsApp` or any app to be able to write it should be the owner or maybe  the owner should be `everyone` .. that is the case here as well but the issue is *how can I selectively prevent it from overwriting just one file*  - implement this at file level   ?  alternatively how do I conceive a method that periodically overwrites the the original file with the one I have... after detecting that it has changed.

btw : my `APK` and `data`  is linked to to second `partition` which is `ext4` via `apps2SD`

Comment: If the file is located under `/data/data/com.whatsapp/...` then only WhatsApp itself can write the file (or an app that uses root permissions) if you have not messed up the directory/file permissions.

Comment: i think the file is simply re-created **because** it can't accessed

Comment: yes that is the design directory private to an app is owned by the app. my question was if `root ` created a file in a private directory   & marked it  `444 ` how can app hv privilege to del it & create its own file .  how can I prevent that behavior?

Comment: it's not the app. looking into */data/system/uiderrors.txt* might give you idea how package manager handle wrong file permissions

Comment: opened that file & I do not see any recent reference to   `  WhatsApp ` and definitely won't find that file ` com.whatsapp_preferences.xml `  but it is being replaced  (after deletion  ) I think and even the ownership changes as well as the privileges. if `root ` created an object anywhere and made it read-only how is it that a standard user can mess around with regardless of whether it is it is private `directory `

Comment: right. it's for uid (not permissions).. anyway, why do you think *a standard user* does this (and not *package manager* which has privileges)?

Comment: well it could be ` package manager ` as well but I assumed based on the fact that the owner was the `app WhatsApp `

Comment: replacing the file at startup every time which means I should make the changes every time at boot via init scriot

Comment: what is your namespace isolation settings?

Comment: `global namespace ` mode out of `isolated inheritent  and global `

Comment: You can make file immutable using `chattr` but that is very likely to break the app when it fails to write its own preferences file.

Comment: ok ✅ I could make the file  `read only ` but now it will not respect the changed parameters at least one of them may be others will be respected. ` multicast_limit_global ` value is being ignored. wonder how it is overriding that and considering the default ? I think the server refreshes the default value and copies them locally and now that it is not able to do so it is somehow taking into consideration its own values.  strange part is it used to work immediately after I made the change and then on the file refresh issue disappeared because I made the file genuinely read only but it it disr

Answer (score 2):

Changing the permissions of the file can solve the problem.

Get the WhatsApp system group, you can use:

```
ls -la /data/data/com.whatsapp
```

Let's suppose that the WhatsApp system group is **u0_a301**.

Change the owner of the file to root and the group to WhatsApp group:

```
chown root:u0_a301 /data/data/com.whatsapp/shared_prefs/com.whatsapp_preferences.xml
```

Then remove the write permission to the group:

```
chmod 640 /data/data/com.whatsapp/shared_prefs/com.whatsapp_preferences.xml
```

That will prevent WhatsApp from writing the file and it can read it.

Comment: I tested it and it works, the file is not overwritten but I did not test if all the application works as expected.

Comment: I've already had tested `file permissions `  but the above answer was written as if with full  optimism which made me think maybe I haven't tested all cases . as I verified it gets overwritten on `reboot `.

Comment: :/data/sdext2/data/com.whatsapp/shared_prefs # ls -al com.whatsapp_preferences.xml -rw-rw---- 1 u0_a209 u0_a209 5948 2020-08-19 20:06 com.whatsapp_preferences.xml :/data/sdext2/data/com.whatsapp/shared_prefs # `chown & chmod ` both having reset

Comment: Strange! I tested it and it persist even after I rebooted multiple times and killing WhatsApp with `am force-stop com.whatsapp".

Comment: in fact even without reboot it is periodically checking for the file and `resetting the perms and rewriting data ` do you have the same Android version and this is the latest version of `WhatsApp ` ( in fact we may not be too concerned about the version because below a certain version they will not let you connect to their network )

Comment: The permissions are not overwritten in my case after rebooting and killing the App. `-rw-r-----  1 root    u0_a301 5742 2020-08-19 10:24 com.whatsapp_preferences.xml` the file still have the same permissions with the latest version of WhatsApp and Kernel version: 4.14.112 . Did the file change permissions after reboot only or at each time you open WhatsApp ?

Comment: are you by any chance running selinux permissive (SuperSU)? or lower android version?

Comment: No, SELinux is in enforcing mode. Android 10.

Comment: mine is `permissive `  ... and whatever I do even without `reboot ` it will periodically rewrite that file. I think you may be working on a laptop with simulated  environment of  Android. . . I had seen this in lower `Android ` versions also but never really pay serious attention.